# How do I check if we are inside a weekly time window in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time, window

I need to run code in a particular time window every week, and an equivalent that runs if we're outside that window. It needs to be daylight savings smart.

The window is between 19:55 and 21:05 Dublin timezone time every Thursday, and if within that time period run functionX(), else run functionY().

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Dublin");
$currentDay = date("N");
$currentTime = date("H:i"); 

if (($currentDay == 4) && (($currentTime >= strtotime("19:55:00") ) && ($currentTime <= strtotime("21:05:00") ) ) ) {
    functionX();
} else {
    functionY();
}
```

Am I on the right track with this, and is there a better way to do this logic?

Comment: if it works, then all is well; is this run for every one hitting a web page?

Comment: It's not working currently. Yes, it will run for everyone hitting the page - bad idea?

Comment: Aren't you missing a closing bracket **)** at the end? And what's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Oh, and next to the bracket issue, you're comparing **$currentTime** (a regular string, [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)) with integers (Unix timestamp, [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)). You'll probably want $currentTime to be a Unix timestamp integer as well. Try using

```
$currentTime = strtotime("now")
```

#### Complete code:

```
$currentDay = date("N");
$currentTime = strtotime("now");

if ( ($currentDay == 4) && ($currentTime >= strtotime("19:55:00")) && ($currentTime <= strtotime("21:05:00")) ) {
    functionX();
} else {
    functionY();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$schedToday = '11am-5pm';

isBusinessOpen($daytoday]);

function isBusinessOpen($time_str){
    //Get the position of the dash so that you could get the start and closing time
    $cut = strpos($time_str, '-');
    
    //use substring to get the first windows time and use strtotime to convert it to    
    $opening_time = strtotime(substr($time_str, 0, $cut));
    
    //same as the first but this time you need to get the closing time  
    $closing_time = strtotime(substr($time_str, $cut + 1));
    
    //now check ifthe closing time is morning so that you could adjust the date since most likely an AM close time is dated tomorrow
    if(strpos(strtolower(substr($time_str, $cut + 1)), 'am')){
        $closing_time = strtotime(date('m/d/y') . ' ' . substr($time_str, $cut + 1) . ' + 1 day');
        $opening_time = strtotime(date('m/d/y') . ' ' . substr($time_str, 0, $cut));
    }
    //to get the current time. take note that this will base on your server time
    $now = strtotime('now');    

    // now simply check if the current time is > than opening time and less than the closing time
    return $now >= $opening_time && $now < $closing_time;
}
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations when you answer a question.